# TCP FAST OPEN on Android

Tags: android, c, linux, tcp, android-ndk

Has anyone succeded to use TCP Fast Open Option on Android?

I use this code inside an Android NDK C program:

`sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
sendto(sfd, data, data_len, MSG_FASTOPEN, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, addr_len);`

as suggested at http://lwn.net/Articles/508865/

It compiles fine both on Linux and Android.

It works flawlessy on Linux but on Android when it calls sendto() the program exits.

I tried it on Android 4.* and 5.1 (devices) and even on Android 6 (emulator only for now).

PS
I noticed that on Android 4.* at `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/` there's no `tcp_fastopen` file, on Android 5.1 the file is there but it contains 0.

Comment: "It works flawlessy on Linux" ... Android uses Linux.

Comment: I know it but Android doesn't behave always as you expect from Linux.

Answer (score 2):

TCP fast open requires Linux kernel 3.7+. Check the kernel version first.

Here's [a sheet](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/51656/181631) of kernel versions in AOSP. Note that it might to represent the real kernel version on your device.

If it's supported, you need to enable it using `echo 3 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen`. It requires root permission.

Comment: P.S. It seems tcp fast open has been enabled by default in the recent Android versions.